# Exporting QGIS 3.14.16-Pi Project to Shapefiles

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS project (3.14.16-Pi). All the layers in the project are linked to KML files. I need to export this entire project to shape files. I can export it layer by layer, but as there are many layers, this will be very time consuming. Is there an easier/faster way to do this? Maybe a plugin that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have additional help from people of the dedicated [GIS Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) that is often really useful to me.

Comment: Easier/faster  i don't know anyway you could try writing code in python for save layers  as shape files ..take a look at QGIS Python API for you QGIS versione